# ¿Cómo Liberar Memoria de Lista Enlazada en C?

Tags: c

Supongamos que tengo una lista simple y ya inserte varios Nodo.
¿Cuál de esta opciones para Liberar Memoria es la correcta 1 ó 2?

Siempre me dijeron que no toque al nodo *cabeza

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Nodo{
  int dato;
  struct _Nodo *siguiente;

}Nodo;

//Prototipos
void LiberarNodos( Nodo *cabeza);


int main(){
  Nodo *cabeza=NULL;


return 0;
}




//OPCION 1
void LiberarNodos( Nodo *cabeza){
        Nodo *test;
        test=cabeza;
        while( test !=NULL){
            free(test);
            test=test->siguiente;
         }
        }


//OPCION 2
void LiberarNodos( Nodo *cabeza){
        Nodo *test;

        while( cabeza !=NULL){
            test=cabeza;
            cabeza=cabeza->siguiente;
            free(test);
         }
        }
```

La Opción 1 es propuesta por mi, pero no la he visto en ningún tutorial. En La Opcion2 sí aparece en algunos pero Pareciera que no Libera al Primer Nodo empieza por el Segundo Nodo.

Answer (score 3):

**Opción 1**

El problema de esta opción queda retratado en los comentarios que he añadido.

```
void LiberarNodos( Nodo *cabeza){
    Nodo *test;
    test=cabeza;
    while( test !=NULL){
        free(test);            // liberas memoria
        test=test->siguiente;  // acceso a puntero no valido
     }
    }
```

Una vez que haces `free(test)`, el puntero pasa a ser no válido y la razón es que la memoria liberada puede ser utilizada por otro hilo o proceso, por lo que lo apuntado por `test->siguiente` no es confiable... puede que te funcione bajo ciertas condiciones pero no es un código seguro.

**Opción 2**

Este caso solventa el problema que hemos comentado para la opción 1. Es decir, recuperas `cabeza->siguiente` antes de liberar la memoria.

Esta opción, no obstante, podría mejorarse con tres pequeños cambios:

- Mejores nombres de variables
- Reducir el ámbito de `test`
- Tabulación coherente

Algo así:

```
void LiberarNodos( Nodo *cabeza)
{
    while( nodo !=NULL)
    {
        Nodo * temp = nodo;
        nodo = nodo->siguiente;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La opción 1 no la has visto en ningún tutorial porque (tal y [como ha señalado eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/311551/2742)) no es correcta.

La opción 2 es correcta pero tal y [como ha señalado eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/311551/2742) mejorable.

En mi caso, querría proponer dos alternativas a tu código y a las propuestas de eferion.

#### Recursividad.

Puedes liberar recursos de manera recursiva:

```
void LiberarNodos(Nodo *nodo)
{
    if (nodo)
    {
        LiberarNodos(nodo->siguiente);
        free(nodo);
    }
}
```

La función se va llamando a si misma con el siguiente nodo hasta dar con un nodo nulo, momento en que finaliza la recursión; sólo después de haber liberado los nodos hijos se libera el nodo del que éstos cuelgan.

Esta aproximación es clara y directa, pero no sería aconsejable en listas con muchos elementos.

#### Bucle `for`.

En general, se considera que el bucle `while` se debe usar cuando no se sabe con seguridad cuantas vueltas necesitará el bucle para completar la tarea mientras que se considera que el bucle `for` debe ser usado en caso contrario.

En tu caso sabemos exactamente cuantas vueltas requiere el bucle, por lo que la implementación con `for` sería:

```
void LiberarNodos(Nodo *nodo)
{
    if (nodo)
    {
        for (Nodo *actual = nodo, *siguiente = nodo->siguiente;
             actual;
             actual = siguiente, siguiente = siguiente->siguiente)
        {
            free(actual);
        }
    }
}
```